# Norm of an operator variations

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I see in papers that people use the following

Operators are bounded, and $|A|=(A^{\ast}A)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
$$\sup_{||x||=1}\langle (|A|^{2}+|B|^{2})x,x\rangle =|||A|^{2}+|B|^{2}||$$

I am confused as, isn't $$||T||=\sup_{||x||=1}||Tx||$$ and $$||Tx||=(Tx,Tx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

That would mean that $$||T||=\sup_{||x||=1}(\langle Tx,Tx\rangle)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

It looks like they are using norm definition $$||T||=\sup_{||x||=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$$??

Thank you for helping me, I am a bit confused about the notation or something it seems.

Comment: $||T||=\sup_{||x||=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$ is not always true. False for rotation by $90^{o}$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$.  It is true for  self adjoint operators. See https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch8.pdf

Comment: Hello there. In the article you linked me, on the page 12 there is an equality
$$||A||=\sup_{||x||=1}|\langle Ax,x\rangle |.$$ The authors in the papers I am reading take sup of for example $$\langle (|A|+|A|^{\ast})x,x\rangle$$ and obtain $$|||A|+|A^{\ast}|||$$
I believe that $$\sup_{||x||=1}|\langle Ax,x\rangle |$$ is the definition of the numerical radius, from what I know. Please explain further if possible.

Comment: The operator $|A|+|A^*|$ is self-adjoint so the formula $$\||A|+|A^*|\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle (|A|+|A^*|)x,x\rangle $$ is correct.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The formula $$||T||=\sup_{||x||=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$$ is valid only for self adjoint operators?  If so, can you please provide a proof or link me to the source. Thank you so much. If possible, could you give me your email so I can ask you in the future if possible. Thank you so much again for the answer!

Comment: If $A$ is selfadjoint, from the definition I wrote above, we get
$$||A||=\sup_{||x||=1}(\langle A^{2}x,x\rangle )^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ I guess this should simply to just $$||A||=\sup_{||x||=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle$$? Any hint on how ?

Comment: A more elementary proof that this works when $T$ is positive (which is the case you have here): $\sup_{||x|| = 1} <Tx, x> = \sup_{||x|| = 1} <T^{1/2}x, T^{1/2}x> = \sup_{||x|| = 1} ||T^{1/2}x||^2 = (\sup_{||x|| = 1} ||T^{1/2}x||)^2 = ||T^{1/2}||^2 = ||T||$.

Comment: (Then again, arguably I’m just hiding the difficulty in the existence of functional calculus as well as that final equality. So this probably isn’t really “elementary”.)

Comment: Dear, thank you so much for answering. Hope I can ask some more if possible.
Why is $T$ positive? Because $\langle Tx,x\rangle = \langle T^{\frac{1}{2}}x,T^{\frac{1}{2}}x\rangle$ and this is positive because it is in the form $\langle x,x\rangle ?$ Another question, the last equality follows from what? I know that $||T^{n}||=||T||^{n}$ but this works for normal operators, but for $n\in N$ I believe.